# How to count the total lake area in an Atlas

Tags: java, openstreetmap

Once I have loaded an [Atlas](https://github.com/osmlab/atlas/tree/5.2.4#atlas) object in memory, what is the best way to count the total lake area? Doing a simple tag search finds all the simple `Area` lakes but I am missing all the lakes based on type=multipolygon `Relations` that are built on "outer" ways that, stitched together, make a full lake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlas comes with a [`ComplexEntity`](https://github.com/osmlab/atlas/tree/5.2.4/src/main/java/org/openstreetmap/atlas/geography/atlas/items/complex#complex-entities) concept that allows the user to construct higher-level entities based on specific concepts. The `ComplexWaterEntity` object should fit that need:

```
Atlas atlas;
Iterable<ComplexWaterEntity> waterEntities =
    new ComplexWaterEntityFinder().find(atlas);

// Get all water bodies and keep lakes only.
// This will include the multipolygon ones.
Iterable<ComplexWaterBody> lakes = Iterables.stream(waterEntities)
    .filter(entity -> WaterType.LAKE == entity.getWaterType())
    .map(entity -> (ComplexWaterBody) entity);

// Add all the surface areas
Surface result = Surface.MINIMUM;
for (ComplexWaterBody lake : lakes)
{
    result = result.add(lake.getGeometry().getSurface()));
}
System.out.println(result.asKilometerSquared());
```