# Filter polygons by area

Tags: openstreetmap

I try to filter the polygons of an .osm by their area. 
Now it's about swiss lakes. I extracted all the polygons using the "natural=water" filter, but I still have all the ponds of Switzerland. Therefore I try to add a filter using the area of the polygons.
How can I do it??

I have allready searched some solutions, but was unable to find good answer.
The best I found was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47078123/filter-shapefile-polygons-by-area) but I don't know where I should execute it and if it is compatible with osm data.

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this issue would be to use [Atlas](https://github.com/osmlab/atlas). Here are the steps you would need to follow (with links to other related SO answers inline):

1. Convert your OSM file to a `.osm.pbf` using [osmosis](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis#Example_usage)
2. Load the `.osm.pbf` into an Atlas file, using [atlas-shell-tools](https://github.com/osmlab/atlas/tree/dev/atlas-shell-tools)'s `pbf2atlas` subcommand
3. Write a small Java class that opens the Atlas file, gets all the lakes using a [`TaggableFilter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56188230/how-to-use-tag-filtering-in-atlas/56399063#56399063), and then [filters them by area, using `Polygon.getSurface()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53199589/how-to-count-the-total-lake-area-in-an-atlas/53199590#53199590).